# Is there a shorthand way to declare a control and subscribe event handlers to it?

Tags: c#

Usually when I'm using C# with XAML or Xamarin I tend to create objects and assign properties directly like this:

```
StackLayout mainStackLayout = new StackLayout() { Padding = 15 };

mainStackLayout.Children.Add(new Button() {
    Text = "Clicky!",
    FontSize = 12
}
```

Then when I realize I want to assign an event handler to it later, I come back and have to do:

```
StackLayout mainStackLayout = new StackLayout() { Padding = 15 };

var btn = new Button() { Text = "Clicky!", FontSize = 12 }
btn.Clicked += (sender, args) => { DisplayAlert("Hello!"); }
mainStackLayout.Children.Add(btn)
```

I really enjoy using lambdas for this (and in general) but I always wondered if there is a way to combine the two methods and subscribe an event handler to the control without having to use a temp variable?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating view-level objects in C#, you should use declarative XAML instead. Why are you using this approach?

Comment: Because I'm auto generating grids based on data from an API so I found it easier to just use a C# Content Page

Comment: You could write an extension method for IList<> that substitutes Add() so it returns the added object instead of int.  Fluent style is, erm, for fans.

Comment: XAML's DataGrid supports dynamic columns and layout - so I'm still not convinced this is the best approach.

Comment: @HansPassant What exactly do you mean with the part 'so it returns the added object instead of int'?

Comment: The Add() method has a return value, it is int.  That is not useful to you, so write another one that returns the added object.  Now you can keep going, mainStackLayout.Children.Add(/* yadayada */).Click += blabla.  Next thing you might do is write an extension method named Subscribe() so you can keep subscribing, etcetera.  Do bounce this off on your friends/team members, this style isn't everybody's cup of tea.

Comment: I recommend writing your code in style #2 all the time, after all a button without a click handler doesn't do much.

Comment: I see what you mean, that's quite a neat trick! Would have never thought about it. This is a style I like for personal projects I just always thought of event handlers as function pointers so I never understood why you can't directly assign them like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an `event` cannot be assigned to in an initializer.

> I never understood why assigning them has to be done through the += operator

That is the main purpose of the `event` keyword. An event is a special property around a delegate, providing extra strong encapsulation.  `+=` and `-=` are the only operations allowed.

The thing that irks you here is that delegates/events are multi-cast. Allowing a simple `foo.Click = myHandler;` could potentially overwrite other subscribers. `+=` means adding to a list. And `+=` is not compatible with the initializer syntax.

So a special feature would be needed, a special case would be needed to allow `+=` in the initializer or to redefine `=` to mean `+=` for events there.

But, as the saying goes, "features start with a score of -100 ..."

Comment: Indeed, had sent suggestion to MS on implementing this quite some time ago. It feels natural to have such a feature in my opinion.

Comment: When I use C# for personal projects I tend to write like this as it feels natural. Since I come from a  C++ background I always thought of event handlers as function pointers so I never understood why assigning them has to be done through the += operator

Comment: @Ilhan Because `event` members are syntactic sugar around essentially what is a `List<Delegate>` which is how multicast function pointers work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ugly workaround for this - taking advantage of the fact properties can have setter-logic. This only works for types that you have control over, however:

```
public class Button2 : Button
{
    public EventHandler Clicked2
    {
        get { return this.Clicked; }
        set
        {
            this.Clicked += value;
        }
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
Button2 btn = new Button2()
{
    Text = "Clicky",
    FontSize = 12,
    Clicked2 = new EventHandler( (s,e) => this.DisplayAlert("Hello!") )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered another hack that might work.

In C# 6, the Collection Initialization syntax previously required the object to implement `IEnumerable<T>` and have a method named `Add` (using duck-typing, it does not need to implement `IList<T>`).

In C# 7, the `Add` method requirement has been loosened to now accept an extension method, though the `IEnumerable<T>` requirement persists.

So we can use an extension-method `Add` to "inject" our multi-statement function (to add an event-handler), we just need to find a way via a member that uses `IEnumerable<T>`.

Now while `System.Windows.Controls.Control` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` itself, we can examine the members of the inheritance hierarchy and see we can latch on to `UIElement.CommandBindings` - or any other collection member that has an internal reference to the object we want, such as `InputBindings` (it is entirely coincidental that `InputBindings` could be used to set-up event-handlers anyway, but that's a red-herring).

So if we have this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo _ownerField = typeof(InputBindingCollection).GetField("_owner", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public static void Add(this InputBindingCollection list, String eventName, Delegate handler)
    {
        Object ownerValue = _ownerField.GetValue( list );

        DependencyObject owner = (DependencyObject)ownerValue;
        // We assume it's a XAML Control instance:
        Control ownerControl = (Control)owner;

        switch( eventName )
        {
            case "click":
                ownerControl.MouseDown += (MouseButtonEventHandler)handler;
                break;
            case "keydown":
                ownerControl.KeyDown += (KeyEventHandler)handler;
            break;
        // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

...we can now add event-handlers - or invoke any multi-statement code - using initializer syntax!

In your case, I can now add event-handlers like so:

```
Button btn = new Button()
{
    FontSize = 12,
    Content = "button text",
    InputBindings =
    {
        { "click", (MouseButtonEventHandler)( (s, e) => DisplayFoo("clicked!") ) }
    }
};
```

This is a huge hack that uses Reflection to get at the target `UIElement` object - I think it can be improved by using another approach to get the `UIElement` - perhaps by passing-in a sneaky subclass of `InputBinding` into the `InputBindingCollection` to catch it via some callback.

The explicit naming of events can also probably be improved too.

### Update:

I see that most XAML components (at least in WPF) use `RoutedEvent` objects to identify events - that means we can make this both simpler and more strongly-typed without resorting to string hacks:

```
static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo _ownerField = typeof(InputBindingCollection).GetField("_owner", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public static void Add(this InputBindingCollection list, RoutedEvent routedEvent, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        UIElement owner = (UIElement)_ownerField.GetValue( list );;
        owner.AddHandler( routedEvent, handler );
    }
}
```

Event-handlers can be added like so:

```
Button btn = new Button()
{
    FontSize = 12,
    Content = "button text",
    InputBindings =
    {
        { Button.ClickEvent, (s, e) => DisplayFoo("clicked!") },
        { Button.LoadedEvent, (s, e) => DisplayFoo("loaded!") }
    }
};
```

Because of method overloading, we can still support non-`RoutedEvent`-type events using my previous strategy. **But we can also generalize this to accept any `Action<T>` callback:

```
static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo _ownerField = typeof(InputBindingCollection).GetField("_owner", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    public static void Add(this InputBindingCollection list, RoutedEvent routedEvent, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        UIElement owner = (UIElement)_ownerField.GetValue( list );;
        owner.AddHandler( routedEvent, handler );
    }

    public static void Add(this InputBindingCollection list, String eventName, Delegate handler)
    {
        UIElement owner = (UIElement)_ownerField.GetValue(list);
        EventInfo eventInfo = owner.GetType().GetEvent( eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public );
        eventInfo.AddEventHandler( owner, handler );
    }

    public static void Add<T>(this InputBindingCollection list, Action<T> callback)
        where T : UIElement
    {
        T owner = (T)_ownerField.GetValue(list);
        callback( owner );
    }
}
```

Which means we can do this:

```
Button btn = new Button()
{
    FontSize = 12,
    Content = "button text",
    InputBindings =
    {
        { Button.ClickEvent, (s, e) => DisplayFoo("clicked!") },
        { Button.LoadedEvent, (s, e) => DisplayFoo("loaded!") },
        { nameof(Button.ContextMenuClosing), (ContextMenuEventHandler)((s,e) => DisplayFoo("context menu closing")) },
        { (Button b) => b.Click += (s, e) => DisplayFoo("clicked 3!") },
        { (Button b) =>
        {
            b.Click += (s, e) => DisplayFoo("clicked 3!");
            b.ContextMenuClosing += (s, e) => DisplayFoo("context menu closing 2");
        } }
    }
};
```

Note you need to specify the types of the callback parameters so type-inference can fill-in the `T` for the `Action<T>`.

Y'know - I'm surprised at how well this works. I might even use this in my own projects.

### Update 2

I spent some time to see if it could support scenarios where Reflection isn't available - by avoiding the need to reflect `InputBindingCollection._owner` by subclassing `InputBinding`, however the `DependencyObject` for the inheritnace-context just isn't exposed anywhere unfortunately.

I took another stab by looking at `BindingGroup` which is the only class that exposes the `InheritanceContext` via `BindingGroup.Owner` (which all `Control` types have), but unfortunately there's no way to get to an `IEnumerable` with which to attach our `Add` method.

### Update 3

I realised there's another approach that can be used, taking advantage of the fact the "emitted" value of an object-initializer expression is the object itself (as opposed to `void`), so you can just do this:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static T Exec<T>(this T item, Action<T> callback)
    {
        callback( item );
        return item;
    }
}


Button btn = new Button()
{
    FontSize = 12,
    Context = "button text"
}.Exec( b => {
    b.Click + (s,e) => ... ;
    b.DoubleClick + (s,e) => ... ;
} )
```

Comment: @Ilhan I've updated my answer with an improved version that lets you use any callback, with different ways of attaching event-handlers.

Comment: Woah thanks for the enormous effort! This, in a way, is what I hoped for C# to have  which it apparently doesn't. Maybe at some point :).. I really like the idea of just 'describing' how the control should behave as 'language-like' as possible which is the ideology of OOP @Dai